# TQDM and multiprocessing - python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, tqdm

I want to use 4 python processes and tqdm progress bar in each of them:

```
 66%|███████████████████████████▌              | 80/122 [00:44<00:23,  1.79it/s]
 35%|██████████████▉                           |  18/52 [00:08<00:16,  2.01it/s]
 26%|█████████▋                                | 61/108 [00:44<00:34,  1.38it/s]
 56%|███████████████████████▋                  | 61/108 [00:44<00:34,  1.38it/s]
```

so they are all 4 displayed and updated like one at the same time.
How can I achieve that ?

Comment: you are expecting to see one progress bar?

Comment: See the `position` parameters in https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#parameters

Comment: @SreeramTP I want to see all 4 of them

Comment: Please edit your questions to add some code we can look at to help you.

Comment: You could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58683903/8170714, easier and more flexible than the answer here imo.

Answer (score 11):

```py
import multiprocessing
import random
import time

import tqdm


def task(position, lock):
    total_iterations = 5

    with lock:
        bar = tqdm.tqdm(
            desc=f'Position {position}',
            total=total_iterations,
            position=position,
            leave=False
        )

    for _ in range(total_iterations):
        time.sleep(random.uniform(0.5, 1))
        with lock:
            bar.update(1)

    with lock:
        bar.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = multiprocessing.Manager().Lock()

    with multiprocessing.Pool(4) as pool:
        for position in range(4):
            pool.apply_async(task, args = (position + 1, lock))

        pool.close()
        pool.join()
```

**Explanation**

- Using `tqdm`'s position flag (as suggested in the comments), I set the line number to print each bar on.
- I use a `Lock` instance to prevent multiple processes writing to stdout at the same time.

Comment: @D Hudson, Code works, how do I modify it so function task takes an argument, and return some value ?

Comment: Great - please accept my answer! This is a new question, it wouldn't be good practise for me to alter the answer for a follow up question. The `args` tuple are the arguments going into the `task` function, just add another there. Try this reference for fetching results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42843203/how-to-get-the-result-of-multiprocessing-pool-apply-async